# How to solve this? AWS updateAutoScalingGroup - error: AccessDenied: You are not authorized to use launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, autoscaling

> (Solved)
>
> I missed this mention on the aws user guide `You can use the AmazonEC2FullAccess policy to give users complete access to work with Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling resources, launch templates, and other EC2 resources in their AWS account`
>
> Now I added permissions as same as on the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy on my custom policy, and the lambda is working well.
>
> The `AmazonEC2FullAccess` has full permissions of CloudWatch, EC2, EC2 Auto Scaling, ELB, ELB v2, and limited IAM write permission.
>
> @Marcin _ Thanks! your comment made me check this part.

I'm trying to update the ASG with 'updateAutoScalingGroup' API on lambda.

But this error "AccessDenied: You are not authorized to use launch template" is blocking me...

At the first time, I applied only related permissions on the IAM policy depend on the document, but now I allowed full permissions of EC2 and Autoscaling on the policy to solve this issue.
But no lucks.

On google, I saw some posts that saying this is just an error, or issue from AMI existence.
But my AMI for the launch template is in the same account, same region...

Could you give me some hint or reference to solve this?

Thanks

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

exports.handler = (event) => {
    const autoscaling = new AWS.AutoScaling()
    
    const { asgName, templateName, version } = event
    
    const params = {
        AutoScalingGroupName: asgName,
        LaunchTemplate: {
            LaunchTemplateName: templateName, 
            Version: version
        },
        MaxSize: 4,
        MinSize: 1,
        DesiredCapacity: 1
    }

    autoscaling.updateAutoScalingGroup(params, async (err, data)=> {
        if(err) console.log("err---", err)
        else console.log("data---", data)
    })
};
```

> Below was added after the comments from Marcin, John Rotenstein, samtoddler

1. Now the policy has full permission for EC2, EC2 Auto Scaling, EC2 Image Builder, Auto Scaling, and some permissions on CloudWatch Logs. But no lucks yet.
2. The AMI is in the same account, same region. And I added the account number on the 'Modify Image Permissions' on it. (I don't know well on this but just tried.)
3. `describeLaunchTemplates()` shows the launchTemplate which I want to use.
4. CloudTrail shows 'RunInstances' and 'UpdateAutoScalingGroup' events. 'RunInstances' returned `"errorCode": "Client.UnauthorizedOperation"`, and 'UpdateAutoScalingGroup' returned `"errorCode": "AccessDenied", "errorMessage": "An unknown error occurred"`
5. Without LaunchTemplate part, API is working well. (I tried update the min and max count only, and it succeed.)
6. Even I changed AMI as public, it's not working for this.

Now I'm trying to search about launch template and AMI related configuration..

Comment: What is the lambda execution role that you are using?

Comment: Does the Launch Template belong to the same AWS Account? If the code calls `DescribeLaunchTemplates()`, does the Launch Template appear in the result set?

Comment: check your launch template configuration, whatever resource you have  configured in the template , you must have access to like AMI, Instance Types, VPC, subnets, IAM, KeyPair, SG etc . Check Cloudtrail for API calls, there you might be able find the exact problem.

Comment: @Marcin _ Created a custom policy and made a role with it. This policy has full permission for EC2, EC2 Auto Scaling, EC2 Image Builder and Auto Scaling now.

@John Rotenstein _ Yes, I copied the launch template from existing launch configuration on the same account, same region. And when I call the `DescribeLaunchTemplates()`, it shows the launch template. 

@samtoddler _CloudTrail shows 'RunInstances' and 'UpdateAutoScalingGroup' event. If you okay, please read the added parts on the question (I added detail information on there)

Comment: IAM:PassRole is a big one people miss.  Your user needs to have permissions to launch the instances in the launch template the ASG is using.  This is so that your ASG can't be used to bypass restrictions on your user/role

Comment: I had the same problem and @Shahad suggestion fixed it for me.

Comment: Down voted this question because it posted the solution in the question - and the solution does not follow principal of least privilege. Also - answers belong in the answers section, not in the question, to enable voting on the individual answers and comments on the individual answers.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the errors provided by AWS in some cases are very unclear and could mislead.

Besides checking that you have the proper rights, this error is also returned when you are trying to create an autoscaling group with an invalid `AMI` or one that doesn't exist.

Comment: Apart from AMIs that don't exist, this can happen with other settings in the launch template that can get blocked, eg: instance size not allowed by an SCP

Answer (score 6):

Actually, problem is your EC2 instance is having an IAM Role which you are not  authorised to use it. Add below policy to lambda or whatever role or IAM user you using to pass the role that is attached to EC2 instance. Once that is done it will start working.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/EC2-roles-for-XYZ-*"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the question asked, using `AmazonEC2FullAccess` does not follow the principle of least privilege.

My use case involves updating an auto scaling group with a newer launch template version. The launch template version has an IAM role specified for the instances. The launch template also specifies tags. The below policy allows updating the auto scaling group with this new launch template version.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/example"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the iam:PassRole permission in your IAM policy for users or roles that are launching instances in ASG, AWS will deny the request to launch instances with an associated IAM role. This means that when a user attempts to launch an EC2 instance and specifies an IAM role for that instance, the iam:PassRole permission is required to successfully launch the instance.

Comment: Down voted because there isn't example permissions here.